# Facebook Video Chat plugin no longer works on Mavericks

Tags: upgrade, macos, java, facebook

After upgrading my Mac OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard to OS X 10.9 Mavericks, I've encountered a minor problem. The video chat plugin of Facebook no longer works. On the Facebook chat box, the video chat icon is no longer visible. I've tried uninstalling the plugin by removing the contents of `~/Library/Application Support/Facebook` but I still haven't seen the video chat icon.

I have installed/setup the video chat plugin of Facebook before and it was working well before the upgrade. I already installed Java on my system since it prompts to be installed after the upgrade.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
```

So, any workaround for this? This is the first issue I've encountered on OS X Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you accidentally blocked a required plugin through Safari's new "power-saving" feature?

Go to Safari Preferences -> Security -> Check "Allow Plug-ins" and click "Manage Website Settings..." -> Make sure www.facebook.com is not blocked from any of the listed plugins.

Comment: it happens on all browser. have tried accessing/checking facebook video chat on Chrome and Firefox, same problems encountered.

Comment: Ah. Seems to be a pretty widespread issue -- my guess is that Facebook will have to update their plugin.

Comment: yeah. i think so too. well, i have seen someone posted this already on facebook help. thanks for the info and for the response. i appreciate it :)